# Its possible do a hole in movieclip with mouse click?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a movieclip moving and when I click him I want that appears a hole.
Its possible do that with actionscript? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hole should appear there the mouse clicks, you could create new `Sprite`, draw two circles (one bigger than your MovieClip, another at size of you hole, both at position of your click) using his `graphics` property. Fill it with any color. It should look like donut.
After that assign created `Sprite` as a mask for your MovieClip.

```
youMovieClipId.mask=createdSpriteId;
```

After that, you could add mask as child of your MovieClip, using

```
youMovieClipId.addChild(createdSpriteId);
```

Now created mask will follow your MovieClip.

Comment: I wonder, can you add that mask somewhere, so that the mask will be moved by acting on its parent, so then once can add both the MC in question and its mask to one parent, hide the mask (via `visible=false`) and move them as a whole?

Comment: Yes, you could add mask as child of your MC, using
`youMovieClipId.addChild(createdSpriteId);`
Using `visible=false` for mask is unnecessary because it will be unseen as long as it acts like mask.

Comment: Okay, I think it'll be better if you add this to the answer, as this will eliminate the problem you describe as remaining.

Comment: @Vesper Fair enough. Done.